# convert two arrays into object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am having an issue making two arrays into one array object.

This is my first array; Lets call it "**keys**". I want to make each item on this array a object key.

```
["name", "age", "gender", "status"]
```

This is my second array which will act as values. let's call it "**header**"

```
[["Luke May", 43, "male", "married"]
["Sarah Saw", 54, "female", "single"]
["Magac gose", 51, "male", "single"]]
```

I want my object to look something like this. let's call it "**arrValues**"

```
[
   {name: "Luke May", age: 43, gender: "male", status: "married"}
   {name: "Sarah Saw", age: 54, gender: "female", status: "single"}
   {name: "Magac gose", age: 51, gender: "male", status: "single"}
]
```

*The problem is that my code has to be **dynamic**, meaning that it will convert perfectly any two array into one object like above.*

[what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd4Ug.jpg)

[What I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzFBj.jpg)

This is my attemp so far:

```
var arrh = header
var data = []
    for(var i = 1; i < header.length; i++){
        var dataToInsert = {}
        var values = arrValues[i];

        for(var x = 0; x < header.length; x++){
            var kx = header[x];
            dataToInsert[kx] = arrValues[x]
        }
        data.push(dataToInsert)
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: So you need two loops. Post the code you tried in your question and not an image

Comment: is your second array exactly in sync with the first array? meaning does it "always" follow the order of name, gender, age, status? Also does it always have exactly the matching number of values and not more?

Comment: Jaya, in somewhat yes. but the values could change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number of values inside of your second array matches exactly the number of keys and that they are in the same order, you can use two loops as follows, the outer loop for looping the 2nd array, the inner loop for the values inside the each array .

```js
var results = [
  ["Luke May", 43, "male", "married"],
  ["Sarah Saw", 54, "female", "single"],
  ["Magac gose", 51, "male", "single"]
];
var keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "status"];

var objectArray = []; // your result

results.forEach(r => {
  let obj = {};
  r.forEach((r, i) => {
obj[keys[i]] = r;
  });
  objectArray.push(obj);
});

console.log(objectArray);
```

Comment: it's useless to use map if you don't return any value, you can use forEach instead

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "status"];

const obj = [
  ["Luke May", 43, "male", "married"],
  ["Sarah Saw", 54, "female", "single"],
  ["Magac gose", 51, "male", "single"]
].map(x => {
  let m = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) m[keys[i]] = x[i];
  return m;
});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is just to give an idea about how can we solve this problem using simple JavaScript (with for loop)

```js
var keys = ["name", "age", "gender", "status"];
var header = [
     ["Luke May", 43, "male", "married"],
     ["Sarah Saw", 54, "female", "single"],
     ["Magac gose", 51, "male", "single"]
];

for(i=0; i<header.length; i++){
  var obj={};
  for (j=0; j<keys.length; j++){
      obj[keys[j]]=header[i][j];
   }
  arrValues.push(obj);
}

arrValues;
```

and the output would be

```js
[
   {name: "Luke May", age: 43, gender: "male", status: "married"}
   {name: "Sarah Saw", age: 54, gender: "female", status: "single"}
   {name: "Magac gose", age: 51, gender: "male", status: "single"}
]
```